# Multiple fileUpload plugin on a page

Tags: java, file-upload, primefaces, liferay

I know it's a simple question I thought, but is it possible to use multiple fileUpload on a page on Liferay? I tried this code but it resulted in plugin misbehaviour. I tried to distinct both fileUpload with an id but still the same.

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{viewBacking.uploadFile1}"
        id="uploader1"
        mode="advanced"
        update="messages,files"
        sizeLimit="100000"
        multiple="true"
        allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(txt|pdf|odt|ods|doc|docx|xls|xlsx)$/"/>

    <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{viewBacking.uploadFile2}"
        id="uploader2"
        mode="advanced"
        update="messages,images"
        sizeLimit="100000"
        multiple="true"
        allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/"/>

</h:form>
```

Comment: Yes, you can use multiple file upload with p:fileUpload on a page on Liferay. There is an example of how to do this in the [primefaces3-portlet](http://www.liferay.com/community/liferay-projects/liferay-faces/demos#primefaces3-portlet) demo.

Comment: @NeilGriffin: Hi thanks, I tried to extract the source and found `applicant.xhtml`, but there is only 1 fileUpload's plugin. I can't find any examples that contains multiple fileUpload.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I thought your question was about multiple="true" -- I would recommend that you try having more than one p:fileUpload component in a plain primefaces webapp. If it works, then try it in a portlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is having multiple advanced fileupload components in same `h:form`

You should use `p:fileUpload` compoments in different forms.

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{viewBacking.uploadFile1}"
     ...
     />

</h:form>

<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{viewBacking.uploadFile2}"
    ...
    />

</h:form>
```

It's possible using multiple `p:fileUpload` components with simple mode in the same form.